# Custom error message for EmptyStackException in Java?

Tags: java

I am implementing Stack in Java. For `pop` operation, I want to throw `EmptyStackException`. According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EmptyStackException.html#EmptyStackException()), `EmptyStackException` has one constructor, `EmptyStackException()`. It -

> Constructs a new EmptyStackException with null as its error message string.

So it cannot take my custom error message as parameter. I need to set custom error message, because it has null as error message and getMessage() returns null. If I use this exception, I have to hard code my error message where I catch `EmptyStackException`.

```
public int pop() {
    if (empty())
        throw new EmptyStackException(); // cannot take error message as argument
    int data = top.getData();
    top = top.getNext();
    return data;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack stack = new Stack();
    try {
        System.out.println(stack.pop());
    } catch (EmptyStackException e) {
        System.out.println("Stack is empty");  // my hardcoded message
}
```

Another way is to use `Exception` instead of `EmptyStackException`. It has a constructor: `Exception(String message)`. Using this, I can set my custom message.

```
public int pop() throws Exception {
    if (empty())
        throw new Exception("Stack is empty"); // take message as argument
    int data = top.getData();
    top = top.getNext();
    return data;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stack stack = new Stack();
    try {
        System.out.println(stack.pop());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()); //print message set from the throwing position
}
```

My question is, which way is the best practice, or is there any other way?

Comment: You could also extend `EmptyStackException` and write a constructor that receives the message, and a `getMessage` that returns your string.

Comment: Why do you need a custom message? There's only one thing an `EmptyStackException` could mean..

Comment: It's parent class is RuntimeException, which does have a cstr that supports a String. Have you tried using a custom message? I never tried it, because imho it's self explanatory already. I would think logging a custom message would be sufficient.

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix  Since `EmptyStackException` means one thing, so is it ok if I print my custom message? I am trying to know which is the best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EmptyStackException` class is self explained. Don't think any additional message required. I would leave it as is :). If you still need message, then creating of custom exception class is widely used approach for this.

Comment: I want to print the error message after catching the exception. But `EmptyStackException` has no error message and I can print nothing but null. So I hard code the message at catch block. Is it in the best practice?

Comment: It is absolutely fine, if you catching EmptyStackException explicitly, e.g. `try {/**/} catch (EmptyStackException e) {this.log.error("Stack is empty");}`

Answer (score 1):

Create your own Custom Exception like this:

```
public class EmptyParameterException extends Exception {

    public EmptyParameterException (String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```